# PHPMailer unable to send mail - The following From address failed

Tags: php, phpmailer, sendmail, ubuntu-16.04

I am getting this error when I am sending mail.

```
Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: The following From address failed: sample@mydomain.com : MAIL FROM command failed,Temporary system failure. Please try again later. ,451,4.3.0SMTP server error: MAIL FROM command failed Detail: Temporary system failure. Please try again later. SMTP code: 451 Additional SMTP info: 4.3.0SMTP server error: MAIL FROM command failed Detail: Temporary system failure. Please try again later. SMTP code: 451 Additional SMTP info: 4.3.0
```

This is my code:

```
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$html = "<b>Hello world!</b>";
$email = "recipient@example.com";
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->setFrom('sample@mydomain.com');
$mail->addAddress($email);
$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = 'Sample Subject';
$mail->Body = $html;

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Email sent';
}
```

I also tried removing `$mail->isSMTP();` and I am getting the echo message `Email sent` the problem with that is when I checked my inbox and spam folder, since I set my personal email as the recipient of the email, the email is not there. Is this a server problem?

I also checked `/var/log/mail.err` , i can see an error log that says this `collect: Cannot write ./dfv4PAGY73013302 (bfcommit, uid=0, gid=119): No such file or directory` - what is that?

I've been banging my heads for 2 days already but I don't know what the problem is. I have installed a fresh LAMP stack in my server, configured postfix also (just saying this, might help you get an idea).

What seems to be the problem here?

Your help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Hmm... it's also possible that your SMTP server is not properly configured. Maybe it cannot write files in the spool directory...

Comment: @axiac how can i write files in spool directory? sorry for that silly question :\

Comment: The SMTP server keeps the content of the emails it handles into a working directory. It seems yours cannot write files in that directory because it doesn't exist. The exact path of this directory is specified somewhere in the configuration of the SMTP server. I never configured `postfix` :-(

Answer (score 3):

Your code is fine. It works and the proof is the fact that you get an error message from the SMTP server. The problem is the data it handles.

A correctly configured SMTP server does not accept to relay emails. Either the `From:` address or at least one of the addresses in the `To:`, `Cc:` or `Bcc:` must be hosted by it in order to accept the email for processing.

Use as `From:` a real email address that is hosted by the SMTP server you use for sending. For example, if you use `smtp.gmail.com` then you have to use your Gmail address as `From:` (and also SMTP authentication in this case).

Your code does not specify a SMTP server; in this case PHPMailer uses `localhost` that, most probably, relays the emails to the SMTP server of your ISP (or of your company if this code runs in the company's intranet). Use the email address provided by your ISP (or your working email address if the code is for your work) as `From:` and it should work.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Actually when I tried removing `$mail->isSMTP();` because I don't want to set up smtp, I get the message "Email Sent", but when I checked my mail inbox and spam folder, the email is not there. Is this a server issue? Thanks again.

Comment: If you remove `$mail->isSMTP()`, PHPMailer defaults to `$mail->isMail()` and that means it uses the PHP function `mail()` to send the email. By default, PHP is configured to use the local `sendmail` program (on macOS and Linux) or the `localhost` SMTP server on Windows. The default configuration may fail in many ways and making it work is more difficult (as it involves the system configuration which, in some contexts, you cannot modify). Using a SMTP server (as you did) in the PHP code is easier. However, the error message clearly says the problem is the email address you use as `From:`

Comment: Ironically, not calling `isSMTP` will do the opposite of what you want. `mail()` requires that you have a local mail server configured; `isSMTP` does not. Using SMTP without specifying a `Host` will attempt to use localhost, and in your case you have a local server running, but it is not configured, hence the error message it gives you. Either send through a different server or fix your local mail server.

Answer (score 0):

Update your PHPMailer. It seems the older versions of PHPMailer don't support self-signed certificates when connecting through TLS SMTP.

I spent two days trying to solve this and in the end I updated PHPMailer and the problem is gone!

My email server is running the iRedMail bundle on Debian 9.

Download the newest PHPmailer zip and extract to PHPMailer folder in your current folder and do:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPOptions = ['ssl'=> ['allow_self_signed' => true]];
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
//etc etc......
```

Answer (score 0):

try with ssl socket in php (example with tls/ssl):

```
// Show errors
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
// Your hostname
$helloHostname = "localhost";

// Emails
$toEmail = "to@email.com";
$fromEmail = "from@email.com";

// Set mx hostname from dns for recipient !!!
$hostnameMX = "mxhost.boo.xx";    

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'verify_peer', false);
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'verify_peer_name', false);
try{
    // echo $socket = stream_socket_client('ssl://smtp.gmail.com:587', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);
    echo $socket = stream_socket_client('tcp://'.$hostnameMX.':25', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);
    if (!$socket) {
        print "Failed to connect $err $errstr\n";
        return;
    }else{
        // Http
        // fwrite($socket, "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: www.example.com\r\nAccept: */*\r\n\r\n");
        // Smtp
        echo fread($socket,8192);
        echo fwrite($socket, "EHLO ".$helloHostname."\r\n");
        echo fread($socket,8192);

        // Start tls connection
        echo fwrite($socket, "STARTTLS\r\n");
        echo fread($socket,8192);

        echo stream_socket_enable_crypto($socket, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_SSLv23_CLIENT);

        // Send ehlo
        echo fwrite($socket, "EHLO ".$helloHostname."\r\n");
        echo fread($socket,8192);

        echo fwrite($socket, "MAIL FROM: <".$fromEmail.">\r\n");
        echo fread($socket,8192);

        echo fwrite($socket, "rcpt to: <".$toEmail.">\r\n");
        echo fread($socket,8192);

        echo fwrite($socket, "DATA\n");
        echo fread($socket,8192);

        echo fwrite($socket, "Date: ".time()."\r\nTo: <".$toEmail.">\r\nFrom:<".$fromEmail.">\r\nSubject:Hello from php socket tls\r\n.\r\n");
        echo fread($socket,8192);

        echo fwrite($socket, "quit \n");
        echo fread($socket,8192);

        /* Turn off encryption for the rest */
        // stream_socket_enable_crypto($fp, false);

        fclose($socket);
    }
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e;
}
```

if you need get hostnames from dns for recipient email domain:

```
function getMX($hostname = "boo.xx", $show = 0){
    if(dns_get_mx($hostname, $mxhosts, $weights)) {
        $i = 0;
        $mxList = NULL;
        foreach($mxhosts as $key => $host) {
            if($show == 1) echo "Hostname: $host (Weight: {$weights[$key]}) <br>";
            $ip = gethostbyname($host);
            if($show == 1) echo "IP " . $ip . "\n<br>";
            if($show == 1) echo "IP " . gethostbyaddr($ip) . "\n<br>";
            $mxList[$i]['host'] = $host;
            $mxList[$i]['ip'] = $ip;
            $mxList[$i]['weight'] = $weights[$key];
            $i++;
        }
        return $mxList;
    } else {
        echo "Could not find any MX records for $hostname\n";
    }
}
```